# Portable Git and GitHub: SSH Keys

Tags: git, ssh, github, rsa, ssh-keys

I downloaded the portable version of Git for Win32, the one that comes in a self-extracting package. I wanted to be able to push commits from anywhere (my flashdrive), but I have no idea how to use a public key that isn't in users/USERNAME/.ssh. How can I configure Git to automatically use keys in another directory?

(I can generate keys in other directories, but Git automatically sends the keys in c:/users/me/.ssh)

NOTE: I am using Win32! Not Linux or OSX!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) will actually use public/private keys in `%HOME%/.ssh`.

By default, msysgit defines HOME to `C:\users\USERNAME`, but nothing prevents you to define `HOME` to any path you want.

Simply define a [user environment variable](http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html) '`HOME`', and then all your shell/DOS sessions will inherit that new value.

Comment: Awsome. I'll just put that in the beginning of the .bat that runs cmd. It worked! Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

You can add your directory to ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile. Also you can try to change the home directory of the user.

Comment: How do I add it? - Git Bash doesn't have access to the folder I'd like to use (in fact, it seems limited in access to the Git folder). How can I use Git cmd to add the directory?

Comment: Where are those files (are they folders)? I've looked in C:/Git, C:/Git/bin, G:/Git, G:/Git/bin, C:/users/me/.

Comment: Oops, I've estimated that you're using Linux or MacOS. Sorry I've no idea for Windows. :(

Comment: Sorry I didn't tell you. I'll add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `core.sshCommand` made it for me.

The idea behind this is to explicitly set path to the key file via `-i` option of the `ssh` command:

```
git config --system core.sshCommand  "ssh -i /d/keys/key.openssh"
```

(I also added my user name - `-l username`, because it's the same for me on all servers I connect to, and I didn't bother to specify it on `git remote` addresses.)

Keep in mind that paths should be given Unix-way, the one above is actually `D:\keys\key.openssh`.

Note: portable Git stores it's system-wide settings in `mingw64/etc/gitconfig` file.